# Repeatedly sample without replacement in R loop

Tags: r, loops, resampling, pmap

Working in R, using the familiar bag of coloured balls analogy. I want to sample without replacement from a bag of balls. In this bag, there are many differently coloured balls. Each colour, c, is represented a random number of times in the bag, k (e.g. k_blue = 3, k_red = 5, k_green = 2, ...). For each c, I want to take a sample without replacement of size k and every ball is taken from the bag at the end of the loop.

I've attempted here:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Generate data
data <- tibble(Colour = paste0("c", 1:1000),
               k = sample(x = c(1:10), size = 1000, replace = T))

# Fill the 'bag' with balls of colour 'C', 'k' times
bag <- unlist(map2(.x = data$Colour,
                   .y = data$k,
                   .f = ~rep(x = .x, times = .y)))


data.2 <- data %>% 
  mutate(Grouped_Colours = map2(.x = Colour, .y = k,
                                .f = ~{
                                  # Take sample of size k without repeatedly sampling the
                                  # same colour (unique() / replace = F) and without
                                  # including each colour in its own group (bag[bag != .x])
                                  .samp <- sample(unique(bag[bag != .x]), size = .y, replace = F)

                                  ### EXCLUDE ALL PREVIOUSLY SAMPLED BALLS (ALSO
                                  ### EXCLUDING THOSE FROM PREVIOUS LOOPS)
                                  bag <- bag[-match(.samp, bag)]

                                  # print out the sample and mutate it into the
                                  # new column 'Grouped_Colours'
                                  .samp
                                })
  )
```

I have indicated in caps where I believe the code is causing the undesired result. Ultimately, I need the entire bag to be sampled (i.e. the bag should be empty and the end).

The problem currently is that the balls are sampled the incorrect number of times in the final dataset and each colour should be sampled exactly k times.

Thank you and please let me know if anything is unclear.

**EDIT 2022-06-03**

I have tried wrapping this sampling process in an `if` statement to separate the initial sampling from all subsequent pulls. Now the loop can't find the previously sampled balls to exclude from the bag.

```
data.2 <- data %>% 
  mutate(Grouped_Colours = pmap(.l = list(..1 = Colour, ..2 = k, ..3 = seq_along(Colour)),
                                # On the first iteration, sample from the global variable 'bag'
                                .f = ~{ if (..3  == 1) {
                                  # Take sample of size k without repeatedly sampling the
                                  # same colour (unique() / replace = F) and without
                                  # including each colour in its own group (bag[bag != .x])
                                  .samp <- sample(unique(bag[bag != ..1]), size = ..2, replace = F)
                                  
                                  # On every subsequent iteration, sample from the function 
                                  # environment variable 'bag' and overwrite the contents
                                } else {
                                  ### EXCLUDE ALL PREVIOUSLY SAMPLED BALLS (ALSO
                                  ### EXCLUDING THOSE FROM PREVIOUS LOOPS)
                                  bag <- bag[-match(.samp, bag)]
                                  .samp <- sample(unique(bag[bag != ..1]), size = ..2, replace = F)
                                }
                                })
  )
```

Comment: Have you read https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2740978/drawing-balls-from-an-urn-with-balls-from-3-different-colors including the code there?

Comment: Is is a requirement that you do it this way (with a loop)?

Comment: Thanks for the reference--I have reviewed this code and question now but it doesn't appear to address the coding problem I have here. Also, the probabilities aren't of great concern to me. As clarified below and demoed in the MWE, the desired result is a list/column of vectors. Together, these contain all of the samples in the bag.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but this seems like a very simple problem.

```
set.seed(1)   # for reproducibility
bag <- rep(c('R', 'B', 'G'), sample(10, 3, replace=TRUE))
bag
##  [1] "R" "R" "R" "R" "R" "R" "R" "R" "R" "B" "B" "B" "B" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G" "G"
sample(bag, replace=FALSE)   # random sample of all balls, without replacement
##  [1] "R" "R" "B" "G" "G" "G" "R" "G" "R" "B" "B" "R" "R" "G" "B" "G" "R" "R" "G" "R"
```

The first line creates the bag with three colors, each present a random number of times (in 1:10). The second line samples the bag without replacement until it's "empty".

Comment: I think you might want something more on the lines of defining the bag as c(rep("red",5),rep("blue",3),rep("green",2)) , wouldn't you?

Comment: The question states: *Each colour, c, is represented a random number of times*, so that's what I was going for. In  OP's example, I guess the random numbers were: 5, 3, 2.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt--the reason it is in a loop is that each colour gets its own vector of length k of other colours, sampled without replacement. Is this more clear? I don't want a single vector of all the sampled elements, rather 'colours' number of vectors, which together contain all of the samples.